Swift Socket.Io client only broadcasts to itself
I'm trying to set up a socket.io app in Swift for messaging. Unfortunately, each client only receives the messages that it individually broadcasts, and sometimes they don't even send anything and instead just reconnect when the sending event is triggered by a button click.
Swift code:
var socket: SocketIOClient!
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: endpoint, config: [.log(true), .forceWebsockets(true), .compress])

override viewDidLoad():
    super.viewDidLoad()
    socket = manager.defaultSocket
    socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) { data, ack in
    print("socket connected)
    }
    
    socket.on("test") { data, ack in
    print(data)
   }
   socket.connect()
}

@IBAction func onClick1(_ sender: Any) {
socket.emit("chat", message)
}

And the flask server code:
@socketio.on('chat')
def handle_message(data):
    """event listener when client types a message"""
    print("data received",str(data))
    emit("test", {'data':'hello','id':'hi'}, broadcast=True)

The "flask-socketio" library is 5.3.6, and the xcode "socket.io-client-swift" library is 16.1.0, which should be compatible with each other. Logs from the heroku server indicate that the clients are connecting regularly and that responses should be getting sent to both of them, but only the sending one receives the "test" response. Am I setting up the events the wrong way so that only the sender can receive anything? Thanks in advance for any advice provided.
